# how to retrieve exact text width for RenderText in Graphics32

Tags: delphi, text, width, graphics32

I think my question is clear enough, but I explain more. Simply, when we are using AntiAlias on RenderText procedure, the value gotten within TextWidth function is not correct. What can I do to get the right text width?

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Comment: yes. it's perfectly done with the code you gave. Thank you again!! I really needed this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look for the algorithm in their own code. They must also calculate it. Anyway this is how I do it.

```
function TGR32Canvas.TextWidth(const Text: string): Integer;
var
  TempFont: TFont;
  TempWidth: Integer;
begin
  if Text <> '' then
  begin
    TempFont := TFont.Create;
    try
      TempFont.Assign(Font);
      TempFont.Size := Font.Size shl AA_MODE;
      TempWidth := GetTextWidth(Text, TempFont);
    finally
      TempFont.Free;
    end;
  end
  else
    TempWidth := 0;

  TempWidth := (TempWidth shr AA_MODE + 1) shl AA_MODE;
  Result := TempWidth shr AA_MODE;
end;
```

The GetTextWidth function is simple. You can do it differently.

```
function GetTextWidth(const Text: string; const Font: TFont): Integer;
var
  Canvas: TCanvas;
begin
  Canvas := TCanvas.Create;
  try
    Canvas.Handle := GetDC(0);
    try
      Canvas.Font.Assign(Font);
      Result := Canvas.TextWidth(Text);
    finally
      ReleaseDC(0, Canvas.Handle);
    end;
  finally
    Canvas.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: from which unit did you get it? GetTextWidth function is unidentified.

Comment: Forgot to show it. I edited the answer. It can probably be done more elegant, but the idea is the same and it works.

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the Windows API function [GetTextExtentPoint32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144938%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) 
Do some google to find example on Delphi

Comment: GR32 uses its own tehniques for drawing so I don't think using the API would give you accurate results.